# how to pass data between services functions in Anguar

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

what I am trying to do here is making a `store()` function in my front-end that creates a new question inside the database but I need to add the. active user id to that question's data before sending everything to the back-end.

this is the actual `store()` function inside my questionsService

```js
store(title : string, content: string, category_id : number): Observable<QuestionsInterface>{

   let user_id : Observable<number>
   user_id = this.authService.getUser()
      .pipe(map(user => {
        return user.id
      })) 
    return this.http.post<QuestionsInterface>(this.baseUrl, {
      title,
      content,
      user_id : user_id,
      category_id
    })
  }
```

the `this.authService.getUser()` returns an Observable that emits the actual user's data trough an interface

the problem here is that I cannot find out how should a treat the `this.authService.getUser()`output to assign it to the `user_id` variable`

do I need to subscribe to the output?

is there a way not to use subscribe? considering that is a single json response that is sent by the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want to use is [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap). `getUser` returns an Observable, `switchMap` will take the emission from that observable and pass the return object from that and create another Observable to be listened to from it.

```
store(title : string, content: string, category_id : number): Observable<QuestionsInterface>{    
    return this.authService
               .getUser()
               .pipe(
                   take(1),
                   switchMap(user => this.http.post<QuestionsInterface>(
                       this.baseUrl,
                       {
                           title,
                           content,
                           user_id : user.id,
                           category_id
                       }));
}
```